# What is causing this shift in layout? CSS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css

I have been following the [RoR tutorial](http://railstutorial.org) and noticed that my layout appears to shift while moving between nav links. Rather than link to my actual project, you can see what I am talking about by looking at the author's personal homepage: [www.michaelhartl.com/](http://www.michaelhartl.com/) If you move between the nav links at the top, the whole page appears to shift. I am guessing that this has nothing to do with RoR, and more with CSS.

Comment: It looks fine to me. What browser are you seeing the problem in? Have you changed any of the default styles in your browser (e.g. custom font sizing, etc.)?

Comment: Chrome 9.0.597.84. Just tried Safari 5.0.3 and the same thing happens. Try moving from the Contact to the About pages.

Comment: Usually a shift on mouseover means the mouseovered item has some kind of :hover effect which affects its size, pushing everything else around. Check for link underlining, borders, etc..

Answer (score 3):

Some pages have scrollbars, some others don't. When the scrollbar appears it shift it left some pixels. (If this is what you mean.)

Answer (score 1):

As Sotiris said, some pages have scrollbars and some don't, due to the amount of content on the page. You can force scrollbars to appear on every page and prevent this apparent 'shift' by putting the following in your CSS file:

```
html { overflow-y: scroll; }
```

Comment: Also note that overflow-y and overflow-x are css3 properties.